# C# PsExec get process list: name, path

Tags: c#, process, psexec

My code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\PsExec\PsExec.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\server-0 cmd /c wmic process get description,executablepath";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string errormessage = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

The console window does not close itself. When I close it manually, I see (in output):

```
Description             ExecutablePath
```

I don't see any other line! But if I write the same in the console:

```
psexec \\server-0 cmd /c wmic process get description,executablepath
```

I see:

```
Description             ExecutablePath
System Idle Process
System
smss.exe
csrss.exe               C:\Windows\system32\csrss.exe
wininit.exe             C:\Windows\system32\wininit.exe
csrss.exe               C:\Windows\system32\csrss.exe
...
```

I tried some ideas like: `Thread.Sleep(...)`, per line reading, `-accepteula`, `EnableRaisingEvents` / `OutputDataReceived` (it does not call), -d flag (no output), `UseShellExecute=true` (works, but I couldn't hide the console window)...

Why do I receive only the first row (in the C# code above)? What should I change to receive the same content I see in the console?

Sorry for the bad English. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Have you asked a question???

Comment: @MichaelBray yes, i need help

Comment: My point was, as it is clear your English isn't great, that you *haven't* asked a question.  Please ask a specific question about your code, if you hope to receive an answer.  As it is, all you have said is "please fix it".

Comment: See here: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MichaelBray, yes, thanks; yeap, my english is bad, sorry; the question is why i receive only first row (in c# code above), what should i change to receive the same i see in console?

Comment: Maybe this question has the answer for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145969/processinfo-and-redirectstandardoutput

Answer (score -1):

Use delegating. Rise event on output received and capture the data. I did the same