# Exception handler hangs on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, shell, tomcat, command-line

I have a big and strange probem with tomcat 7, spring 3.1.1 and windows 7 pro x64.

The problem appear when my web app throws an exception and its is managed by this custom HandlerExceptionResolver:

```
public class JsonHandlerExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JsonHandlerExceptionResolver.class);


    @Override
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response, Object obj, Exception e) {
        Output out=new Output(false);
        out.setException(e.getClass().getName());
        out.setError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        log.error("",e);
        try{
            response.getWriter().println(new Gson().toJson(new Output(e.getMessage(),e.getClass().getSimpleName())));
            response.getWriter().flush();
            response.getWriter().close();
        }catch (Exception e1) {
            log.error(e1);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The http request hangs and I have to stop tomcat to unlock it. In log files I can see the right stacktrace but it is printed only after the tomcat shutdown command (so I understand that tomcat is really hanged).

The strange thing is that this problem appears only if tomcat is started by a C# application (it runs a javaw process with proper arguments), if I try to start it by command line (with **the same** command) the problem does not occur! Mind that this error is not systematic, in many identical systems (win7 + tomcat) it works.
Do you know what can be?

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with your C# App.

Comment: Yes maybe, but why the same command works by cmd? And why only in exception events, the other http request well works!

Comment: If the C# is spawning the Tomcat then maybe there is some problem with shared IO.  Just a guess Sorry.

Comment: This could be a good idea... let me try

Comment: Oh my god. The c# property process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError hangs the jvm. Please answer me and vote down my question! ;-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Guess is that if the C# is spawning the Tomcat then maybe there is some problem with shared IO which can be verified by checking the StartInfo.RedirectStandardError property.

See [ProcessInfo and RedirectStandardOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145969/processinfo-and-redirectstandardoutput) for a long explanation

Cheers