# Getting text from a C console app

Tags: c#, mono

I want to run in Linux (mono, app in C#) a [background console app written in C](https://code.google.com/p/arduino-homeeasy-web-switch-transmitter/downloads/detail?name=temper-1.0.tgz&can=2&q=) and get (for example as string) back the line which begins with the string "Temperature".

I am starting the *temper* process using `System.Diagnostic.Process` and `RedirectStandadOutput`, but I receive only an empty console window with no text - when I run manually *temper* in terminal, everything is working ok.

Comment: Can you show your code where you RedirectStandardOutput? You have to make sure you do something with that output.. (such read it to a string, then write it to the console) Without the code, we can't see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: If you redirect standard out then yes, you're console window will show no text - it's been redirected (by you!!). Now you just need to read it from the place you redirected it to (as @Baldrick says - show us the code).

Comment: This answer here might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1146030/2609288