# How to redirect the output from the console?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm currently trying to read the outputstream from an external console application.
I can not modify this application.

This is to code i'm currently using:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        string dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = dir + "/volibot.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.Start();
        //do some stuff with the stream
```

I use this to read the outputstream:

```
            while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string message = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
```

But whenever I add:

```
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

   bij System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   bij System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   bij System.Console.SetWindowSize(Int32 width, Int32 height)
   bij RitoBot.Core.Main(String[] args)
```

This doesn't make sense because this is a console application?
How can I fix this problem?
Or is there a simple work around?

Edit: 
Tried this: [ProcessInfo and RedirectStandardOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145969/processinfo-and-redirectstandardoutput)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\VoliBot.exe
        Process build = new Process();
        build.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\";
        build.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        build.StartInfo.FileName = "volibot.exe";

        build.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        build.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        build.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        build.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        build.ErrorDataReceived += build_ErrorDataReceived;
        build.OutputDataReceived += build_ErrorDataReceived;
        build.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        build.Start();
        build.BeginOutputReadLine();
        build.BeginErrorReadLine();
        build.WaitForExit();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static void build_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string strMessage = e.Data;
        Console.WriteLine(strMessage);
    }
```

Still didnt work :s

Comment: can you show the code that reads the `StandardOutput` ?

Comment: could it be that there is an error when executing `volibot.exe`? or the path to `volibot.exe` is incorrect

Comment: Volibot runs perfect from the commandline.

Comment: From what I read here: https://communities.ca.com/thread/241697832. Maybe you can try: `process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow  = true;`. Not sure, though

Comment: I guess the code inside `volibot.exe` uses some environment information like [workingdirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx), but these kind of information is not provided in your code, causing volibot to run into errors. When run from commandline, these information is provided by the shell

Comment: Do you maybe know any other ways to get this output data? @KhanhTO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94514/discussion-between-khanh-to-and-user2997204).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\temp\mycommand.exe", String.Format(" \"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", sourceDoc, dataSource, outputFile))
        {
            WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = false
        };

        using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = psi })
        {
            process.Start();
             process.BeginErrorReadLine();
              process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            // wait for the process to exit
            process.WaitForExit();


            if (process.ExitCode != 0)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's giving me the same crash :(

Answer (score 0):

You have @"C:\Users\pc\Documents...."
you don't need double \ when you use the @ sign..

maybe it is that?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that :(