# Reading Output from cmd getting errors

Tags: c#, cmd, redirectstandardoutput

i have been looking up "how to get standard output from cmd" and i found a few tutorials, but none, yes NONE seemed to work, im trying to read all the output that "cmd.exe" has for me.

heres the whole code, Scroll down for the error location

```
    public static string C(string arguments, bool b)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new 
        System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = 
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        string res = "";
        if (b)
        {
            StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
            while (!process.HasExited)
            {
                q.Append(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
            string r = q.ToString();
            res = r;
        }
        if(res == "" || res == null)
        {
            return "NO-RESULT";
        }
        return res;

    }
```

Where i get my error (System.InvalidOperationException: 'StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.')

```
   string res = "";
   StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
   while (!process.HasExited)
   {
       q.Append(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()); // Right here
   }
   string r = q.ToString();
   res = r;
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145969/processinfo-and-redirectstandardoutput)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `ProcessStartInfo` named `startInfo`, then set some properties on `process.StartInfo` and then assign `startInfo` to `process.StartInfo` basically reverting what you set previously.

You should be setting `RedirectStandardOutput`, `RedirectStandardInput` and `UseShellExecute` on the `startInfo`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Thankyou! Someone can read my code better then the creator, Lol.