# Redirect output from Start.Process

Tags: c#

I am trying to redirect the output of my command line program when it is called with `Process.Start()`. I've tried all permutations of `RedirectStandardOutput`, `UseShellExecute` and `CreateNowWindow` and had no luck.

I know there are other ways of accomplishing this such as reading `StandardOutput` after this but I would prefer to redirect it with arguments if possible into a file. I only care about the return code and only need the output of myprog.exe to go to a file. My program doesn't need to know what the output is.

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"myprog.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = " " + InputFilename + " > " + OutputFilename;

p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
var result = p.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ProcessInfo and RedirectStandardOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145969/processinfo-and-redirectstandardoutput)

Comment: Not really. I only care about the output from myprog.exe going to a file. My program doesn't need to do anything with the output of myprog.exe except for get the return value.

Comment: Did you try `cmd.exe` for `p.StartInfo.FileName` and `myprog.exe inputfileName > outputFileName` for `p.StartInfo.Arguments`?

Comment: I didn't think of that but I tried it and it didn't work. The program locked up.

Comment: If you are using redirection (file redirection like > filename) you need ShellExecute = true, as that is a shell (cmd) function. Alternatively you can change your command to invoke a shell directly be like "cmd.exe /c dir > file"

Answer (score -1):

This will work for my issue. Get the output with p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() and write it to a file.